# How to iteratively sum file sizes with given file extensions?

Tags: awk, grep, ls, for

I'm stuck at figuring out how to sum `ls` 5th column result with `awk`. If I add `$bytesum+=...` then the program obviously breaks.
Any ideas?

```
bytesum=0
for i in `cat fileextensions.txt | sort | uniq`
do
    ls -Rl "$folder" | grep $i | awk '{bytesum+=$5}; {print $9 " " $5}'
done

echo $bytesum
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice, http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 for some of the issues with that script. Also `sort | uniq` = `sort -u` and `grep foo | awk '{bar}'` = `awk '/foo/{bar}'` and you don't need separate blocks for every action in awk - `{x}; {y}` = `{x; y}` and `print $9 " " $5` = `print $9, $5` (it's why OFS exists). And  where did `$folder` come from?

Comment: `$folder` is a path to the folder where the script recursively searches for files with given extensions.

Comment: Then add its definition to the script in your question.

Comment: What is the contents of `fileextensions.txt` and do you really need that as a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU find all you need is:

```
find . -type f -printf '%s\n' | awk '{s+=$0} END{print s+0}'
```

With any find:

```
find . -type f -exec stat -c '%s\n' {} \; | awk '{s+=$0} END{print s+0}'
```

To just find and stat files with a specific extension in a specific directory ("folder" is a Windows term, in UNIX terminology it's a directory) as it looks like you might be trying to do would be:

```
dir='whatever'
ext='pdf'
find "$dir" -type f -name "*.${ext}" -printf '%s\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
for size in `du *.jpg | cut -f1`; do sum=$((sum+size)); done; echo $sum
```

Integrate this into yor main loop changing the `.jpg` in my example to a proper variable `$i` in your script.

Comment: See the links I provided under the OPs question for several of the same issues in your script.